# Máscara javascript para entrada de horas

Tags: javascript

Alguém conhece alguma máscara javascript para entrada de horas onde o formato não é HH:mm. 
Vou utilizar para definir o tempo em horas de projeto e alguns deles podem ter mais de 24h. Exemplo 120:00 horas, 200:00 horas e ai vai. As máscaras que consegui só serviam para o formato 24h.

Comment: Já tentou o formatter.js ?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? se tiver `120:00` como quer que apareça? que formatos de entrada tem e que formatos de saída quer?

Comment: Olá Sergio. O ideal seria uma máscara que só permitisse a entrada de números e conforme fossem sendo digitados, a máscara da hora fosse aplicada. Exemplo: se eu digitar os números 2200, a máscara seria aplicada e seria exibido 22:00. Se digitar 32030, com a mascara seria 320:30. Deu pra entender?

Answer (score 5):

Não sei se a utilização de plugins baseados em jQuery é alternativa para o teu projeto, mas existe um plugin excelente para vários tipos de máscara: [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Depois poderias fazer algo do género:

```
$('input').inputmask("99:99");
```

ou formatar a máscara da maneira que precisas.
Este plugin tem também muitas outras funcionalidade interessantes.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando RegEx:

```
/^([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

Dessa forma você pode validar os formatos:

```
9:59 | 09:59 | 009:59 | 100:00 | 999:59
```

Comment: Olá Marcelo, através do RegEx eu consigo aplicar a mascara?

Comment: Sim, consegue. @DouglasCristhian